# How to remember jQuery variable true or false state with a cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a button that when clicked will reveal or hide a series of buttons. What I need to do is remember the state or the variable:

```
is_hidden = false;
```

.. If the page were to reload. I have tried using [jQuery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and doing something like:

```
$.cookie('is_hidden', 'false', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

However I'm guessing it's a mile off how to achieve such a thing. Any help would be appreciated. [Working example](http://codepen.io/vdecree/pen/QbGVXo) found here if it helps (includes the plugin).

Comment: FWIW, given the level of [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage&search=storage) for [web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/), this kind of client-only flag really should be using `localStorage` these days, not a cookie. Simpler code (well, it would be if you weren't using the cookie plugin), and it doesn't make the HTTP requests heavier.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh ok, so I should really be looking at web storage for something like this. I will take a look on Google. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a falsy value like false, "",undefined or null for false and `true`, `1` etc. for true as follows

```
 $.cookie('is_hidden', false, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
 $.cookie('is_hidden', null, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
 $.cookie('is_hidden', "", { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

and

```
 $.cookie('is_hidden', true, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```